# efficient way to determine if logged in customer has previously placed an order

Tags: customer, mysql

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
$firstOrder = $orders->getSize();
```

Currently i'm using the above function to determine the amount of orders that a user has generated, however it seems to be terribly bloated by the sql queries.  Is there a faster method?

I suppose a good way to check temporal efficiency is something like:

```
$timer1=0;
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++){
    $start1=microtime(true);
    $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());
    $firstOrder = $orders->getSize();
    $end1=microtime(true);
    $time1+=$end1-$start1;
}
Mage::log($timer1/$i);
```

Comment: `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());` does not run a query against the database. Of course, it will be faster than `... ->getFirstItem()` in my post. You need to include `$firstOrder = $orders->getSize();` in your loop if you want to make equal comparison.

Comment: @musicliftsme 
 
I added $firstOrder=$orders->getSize() to my loop as shown above and the average time for the first implementation over 5000 iterations was "0.0017097240924835" for your implementation it was "0.0027962175369263".

Comment: Hm, strange. The only reason I can think of why yours is faster is that the number of orders are small and that customer ID exist only in very few records. `getSize()` queries the entire results and runs a PHP `count()` on it, which is a no-no if you just want to check if the customer has had an order in the past. `LIMIT 1` is the way to go. But I could be wrong. :)

Comment: @musicliftsme Ah, of course!  I'm sure your method is faster on the live site.  My local version was using a dummy costumer with no orders -_-.  Thank you sensei.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is an efficient way to check if the customer has at least one order.

```
$order = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId())
    ->setCurPage(1)
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->getFirstItem();

if ($order->getId()) {
    // Has at least one order
} else {
    // No order
}
```

The collection used in this method yields a query like below, which is efficient.

```
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id` 
FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (main_table.customer_id = 'some_customer_id') LIMIT 1
```

Comment: yes but that resource model has like millions of entries in it.

Comment: This is one of the most efficient ways to do what you need using the factory method. The alternative would be to use Varien_Db_Select or a raw query, but I recommend the posted method.

Comment: After 1000 iterations your method proves twice as time consuming as the method I posted above. :\

Comment: sorry, 5000 iterations, almost 3x longer.

Comment: I saw your updated post. My method is absolutely faster. I'll leave a comment in the original post.